# Find local maximum of data files in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a list of data (two columns) and I want to plot in gnuplot only the value for which my second column has a local maximum.

To do so I would like to see if the second column of the ith row is bigger than the (i-1) and (i+1)th rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done and I was bored enough to do it. I generated the following set of random data:

```
5191
29375
23222
32118
3185
32355
17173
8734
28850
20811
5956
6950
28560
25770
4630
28272
10035
7209
19428
26187
30784
20326
12865
23288
20924
```

Plotting the values against their position in the list looks like this:

[image]

You can spot the local maxima right away from the graph above. Now I can process the data points storing the two previous values (both x and y coordinates) in temporary variables, when I identify a maximum, I plot the data point:

```
# Select the columns of your data file that contain x and y data
# (usually 1 and 2 respectively)
xcolumn=0
ycolumn=1

plot "data" u (column(xcolumn)):(column(ycolumn)) w l, \
"data" u (column(0)==0 ? (last2y=column(ycolumn), \
last2x=column(xcolumn), 1/0) : column(0)==1 ? (lasty=column(ycolumn), \
lastx=column(xcolumn), 1/0) : lastx) \
: \
( column(0) < 2 ? 1/0 : (last2y < lasty && \
column(ycolumn) < lasty) ? (value=lasty, last2y=lasty, last2x=lastx, \
lasty=column(ycolumn), lastx=column(xcolumn), value) : (last2y=lasty, \
last2x=lastx, lasty=column(ycolumn), lastx=column(xcolumn), 1/0)) pt 7
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that seems perfect. However, did you have only one column in your file? I have two in my case and I think I need to adapt the code. but I am not sure to understand exactly the meaning of `column(0)`

Comment: I managed to make it work, but now I would like to make lines instead of points, is it possible?

Comment: See the edited answer for a general solution. For lines you'll need to plot to a table (only the points, skip the first `plot "data"`), then filter it to remove the invalid points: `set table "table"; plot ...; unset table; plot "< grep "i" table" w l`.

Comment: I already wrote that but it does not work. If I put linepoints `lp` only the points appear.

Comment: See edited comment. There is a typo, change `"i"` by `'i'` with single quotes (I cannot edit it again).

Comment: As an alternative of the lines, can I save the data (the list of maximum) to an external file?

Comment: @Miguel, thank you very much it works. Is it possible to print the count of the peaks?

Answer (score 6):

### A simple gnuplot peak finder

Comparing 3 consecutive data points is a simple way to look for maxima/peaks.

```
if y(i-1) < y(i) > y(i+1) then you have a maximum/peak at x(i).
```

However, if you have noisy curves (like experimental spectra typically are) you will get too many "peaks".

The script below basically calculates for each peak a specific number which is a measure for the "independence" of a peak (see [Topographic prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence)). Note that a high peak intensity does not necessarily mean high prominence. For the script gnuplot>=5.2 is required since it uses datablocks and `plot ... with table`. With some adaptions, it can maybe run with older versions.

You can give "threshold" to show only a certain number of peaks. Unfortunately, gnuplot does not have an easy internal feature for sorting datablocks, with this one could have easily shown the first N most prominent peaks. Hence, here it is done differently:
`Threshold=100` means show all peaks, `Threshold=0` means show only the global maximum. Note that the threshold values and number of shown peaks are not linear between `0` and `100` since it depends on the spectral shape.

Comments and improvements are welcome.

**Data:** `SO28173128.dat`

```
# x    y
6.02   3.33
9.59   4.03
9.59   4.03
9.59   4.03
9.83   3.66
10.58   3.22
10.62   3.85
11.32   2.33
11.53   3.67
11.88   3.27
13.28   3.97
13.42   4.35
14.56   2.99
14.75   3.50
15.23   3.91
15.59   3.58
16.56   3.85
16.70   4.49
16.97   3.98
17.23   4.49
17.37   3.73
17.90   4.24
17.93   4.91
18.80   4.23
18.83   4.64
20.37   3.59
20.48   3.99
21.70   3.19
22.29   4.36
22.41   3.38
23.34   5.04
23.41   5.38
24.38   4.71
24.58   4.96
25.40   5.13
25.41   4.70
26.20   4.21
26.36   4.84
26.55   4.11
26.79   4.73
27.02   4.13
27.54   4.51
27.55   5.17
28.08   5.42
28.33   4.97
28.61   5.17
29.06   5.10
29.12   4.26
29.61   3.61
30.03   4.84
30.58   5.30
30.68   4.72
31.21   5.82
31.99   5.83
32.58   6.56
33.03   6.23
33.51   6.79
33.73   8.88
34.00   7.85
34.17   9.82
34.32   11.24
34.55   10.78
34.85   12.58
35.14   13.84
35.50   18.07
35.85   18.40
36.55   30.70
36.75   29.27
37.16   28.78
38.15   18.93
38.29   20.52
38.83   14.96
39.63   11.39
40.17   8.67
40.48   9.22
40.88   9.75
40.95   8.77
41.45   10.86
41.58   10.33
41.84   11.12
42.51   12.83
43.33   15.09
43.43   14.20
43.63   14.56
44.22   14.76
44.92   12.58
45.71   9.40
45.98   9.84
47.03   7.01
47.53   7.15
47.95   5.48
48.08   6.21
48.56   4.51
48.64   5.11
49.14   3.69
49.31   4.27
49.86   4.71
50.14   4.13
50.33   5.83
50.37   5.36
51.00   4.60
51.37   4.75
52.00   4.91
52.01   4.34
54.28   3.83
54.46   4.33
54.83   3.19
55.58   5.30
55.86   4.95
55.92   6.48
56.40   5.89
56.59   5.16
57.56   5.96
57.64   5.21
58.31   5.36
58.38   6.08
58.92   5.84
59.00   5.28
59.57   5.96
59.94   5.37
61.31   6.07
61.32   6.78
61.96   7.34
62.37   6.89
63.14   9.45
63.54   9.51
63.80   11.03
63.93   11.56
64.17   11.12
64.84   12.38
65.14   16.28
65.64   18.07
66.22   19.06
66.42   17.70
66.56   18.40
67.10   17.20
67.24   18.00
67.77   16.82
68.04   15.80
68.15   16.88
68.43   14.98
68.86   16.28
69.33   16.55
70.43   29.11
70.93   48.16
71.62   58.09
72.01   66.42
72.43   73.37
72.79   76.74
72.84   81.24
73.07   79.85
73.15   72.04
73.32   74.49
73.58   61.26
73.71   65.36
73.98   51.60
73.98   58.75
74.25   52.93
74.53   39.70
74.90   34.01
75.18   34.80
76.67   23.29
77.05   23.82
77.15   20.94
77.27   27.13
77.52   25.20
77.70   29.76
78.17   29.96
78.36   33.33
78.73   37.05
78.86   34.67
79.03   39.90
79.38   39.70
79.59   40.62
79.88   39.17
80.59   36.52
80.60   33.61
81.26   27.53
81.67   23.69
82.07   23.69
82.90   15.37
83.94   14.04
84.25   14.42
85.01   11.26
85.22   12.18
85.77   11.19
85.89   9.97
86.46   10.72
86.56   11.78
87.06   10.56
87.19   11.53
87.74   9.60
87.89   10.64
88.30   8.74
88.56   9.27
88.98   8.08
89.25   8.70
90.12   9.15
90.14   8.34
90.99   9.59
91.06   8.86
91.72   9.01
91.74   8.48
92.43   7.68
92.48   8.34
93.15   7.68
93.54   8.34
93.72   7.61
94.20   8.00
94.39   8.64
94.82   7.83
95.00   8.40
95.43   6.77
95.66   7.39
95.81   5.44
95.84   6.25
96.53   7.70
96.55   6.70
97.22   9.14
97.47   8.13
97.53   6.75
98.57   7.83
98.85   7.40
98.92   8.45
99.35   8.25
99.40   7.77
100.04   8.33
100.14   7.91
101.00   8.30
101.04   7.80
101.94   7.48
102.02   8.20
102.53   6.56
102.58   7.84
103.23   7.75
103.38   6.82
103.39   8.93
103.75   8.60
104.05   9.26
104.30   8.14
104.55   8.56
104.85   7.15
105.17   10.09
105.21   8.41
105.52   11.78
105.80   10.00
105.92   10.86
106.11   9.54
106.31   9.93
106.86   10.99
107.20   10.88
107.42   12.05
107.62   10.33
107.80   11.16
108.39   9.90
108.79   12.25
109.08   11.85
109.46   13.77
109.73   13.42
109.96   15.16
111.02   20.08
111.30   23.56
111.69   23.56
112.35   30.08
112.61   39.04
112.89   43.53
113.28   43.67
113.81   60.73
113.94   56.63
114.20   63.11
114.46   69.60
115.00   80.44
115.12   86.95
115.27   84.68
115.78   88.78
116.11   89.57
116.40   88.51
116.43   89.90
117.90   80.31
118.18   71.32
118.42   72.51
118.70   67.48
118.83   61.13
119.25   60.34
119.37   54.51
119.65   55.18
120.08   50.28
120.12   48.96
120.84   54.18
120.95   51.87
121.24   56.49
121.50   53.01
121.64   54.44
121.73   51.74
121.84   52.53
122.14   53.72
122.19   52.40
122.44   53.59
122.45   54.91
122.64   51.61
122.76   53.17
123.08   50.79
123.10   50.15
123.34   49.51
123.39   50.81
123.88   50.28
124.25   46.58
124.26   44.06
124.53   43.67
125.18   38.77
125.81   32.16
126.10   32.55
127.32   21.71
127.70   21.18
127.96   18.27
128.22   18.66
128.62   15.71
128.89   16.24
129.30   13.94
129.56   14.47
129.96   12.22
130.21   12.72
130.53   10.83
130.93   10.61
131.15   11.24
131.84   10.06
131.93   11.12
132.71   9.87
133.06   13.17
133.38   12.73
134.17   16.97
134.31   22.37
134.85   30.83
135.38   43.01
135.62   40.09
135.64   50.81
135.75   54.05
136.16   56.10
136.80   50.22
137.21   49.36
138.29   25.41
138.56   26.73
139.98   13.09
140.03   11.92
140.32   14.53
140.55   13.80
140.85   16.25
141.24   15.81
141.45   17.92
141.59   16.51
141.99   20.65
142.25   20.19
142.76   27.79
142.91   24.95
143.72   37.66
143.79   35.37
144.65   29.11
144.91   30.32
145.71   25.74
145.84   24.80
146.54   27.73
146.74   30.57
147.30   31.11
147.42   30.30
148.33   31.23
148.38   30.68
148.93   31.19
149.09   31.74
149.24   28.43
149.49   29.03
149.96   24.55
150.69   23.48
151.83   18.06
151.89   19.39
152.41   18.27
152.96   19.45
153.02   18.53
153.47   19.42
153.71   18.78
153.91   19.44
154.08   17.74
154.54   18.92
154.65   18.20
155.61   18.79
156.78   15.75
157.06   16.08
157.54   12.68
157.84   13.40
158.51   12.73
158.57   11.85
159.45   11.27
159.57   10.33
160.11   8.81
160.24   9.81
160.90   9.27
160.90   8.08
161.17   8.48
161.43   8.10
161.59   8.72
161.83   7.91
162.44   8.48
162.61   7.94
163.41   8.75
163.43   8.19
163.94   8.99
163.96   8.33
164.60   8.23
164.87   8.74
165.81   8.50
166.10   8.08
166.74   8.91
167.02   8.48
167.67   9.68
167.96   9.28
168.90   9.81
168.96   10.34
169.57   9.77
169.76   11.28
170.00   10.75
171.01   13.77
171.12   13.13
171.79   13.71
172.83   19.14
173.19   19.13
173.52   21.06
173.73   20.38
173.87   21.65
174.27   21.90
174.41   25.94
174.94   27.39
175.20   33.48
175.71   35.07
175.84   40.49
176.48   43.27
176.51   46.84
177.34   51.47
177.62   57.30
177.69   55.18
177.87   53.26
178.08   54.46
178.45   49.43
178.76   49.62
179.02   43.53
179.43   42.08
179.96   28.98
180.21   26.40
180.56   26.57
180.57   26.20
181.14   26.43
181.24   25.51
181.68   24.93
181.74   27.13
181.97   28.85
182.05   26.93
182.14   29.78
182.30   27.53
182.59   28.72
182.72   26.93
183.04   27.67
183.21   28.76
183.33   27.92
183.75   29.99
184.06   29.78
184.28   32.07
184.71   32.49
185.40   37.78
185.61   34.01
186.02   33.86
186.20   30.07
186.79   28.72
186.97   25.44
187.34   25.15
188.45   17.65
188.84   16.25
189.08   16.77
189.50   14.08
189.90   13.69
189.92   11.67
190.37   12.04
190.41   12.90
190.90   11.40
190.93   12.58
192.29   9.27
192.33   8.79
193.23   10.21
193.34   9.73
193.78   11.15
194.07   10.20
194.54   10.43
194.93   9.64
195.39   9.82
195.98   10.86
196.08   10.05
196.45   11.78
197.00   8.90
197.03   9.95
197.70   7.15
198.07   10.13
198.10   8.48
198.83   9.67
198.85   10.46
199.27   9.80
199.46   9.46
200.46   11.78
200.73   11.38
201.38   12.37
201.92   9.72
202.06   10.52
203.14   7.67
203.52   7.95
203.93   7.02
204.13   7.55
204.39   6.66
204.63   7.15
206.35   5.53
206.57   6.00
207.21   6.57
207.33   5.76
208.23   7.93
208.52   7.68
208.92   7.15
209.21   7.56
209.41   6.62
209.88   6.89
211.48   4.50
211.70   5.00
212.39   5.37
212.51   4.53
212.84   4.31
212.92   5.17
213.26   4.38
213.44   5.24
213.70   4.57
214.15   4.97
214.24   5.71
215.55   5.20
215.65   6.01
216.28   6.16
216.55   6.87
216.73   5.56
216.95   6.23
217.25   6.03
217.47   5.46
217.93   5.50
218.26   5.83
218.56   5.04
219.31   4.73
219.97   4.72
220.10   5.61
220.79   4.23
220.87   4.94
221.87   4.64
222.07   4.12
222.58   4.47
222.69   5.02
223.21   4.51
223.24   5.22
223.86   4.54
223.90   5.22
224.48   4.29
224.54   5.04
225.22   4.73
225.28   3.86
225.54   4.13
225.76   4.72
225.84   3.93
226.52   4.23
226.60   4.94
226.98   4.02
227.78   3.89
228.29   4.67
228.62   4.29
229.12   4.90
229.46   4.16
229.83   4.48
230.28   3.54
230.50   4.06
230.91   3.03
231.18   3.63
231.79   3.99
231.97   3.45
232.70   4.86
```

***Edit:** revised and simplified*

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### a simple gnuplot peak finder
reset session

FILE = "SO28173128.dat"
colX = 1
colY = 2

# extract all peaks
set table $Temp
    plot y2=y1=x2=x1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=x2,x2=column(colX), \
                                 y0=y1,y1=y2,y2=column(colY), \
                                 y0<y1 && y1>=y2 ? sprintf("%g %g",x1,y1) : '') w table
set table $Peaks        # remove empty lines and store first values in x0,y0 for later use
    plot $Temp u (column(-2)==0 && $0==0?x0=$1:$1):(column(-2)==0 && $0==0?y0=$2:$2) w table
unset table

isNaN(v) = v!=v         # check if value is NaN
min(a,b) = isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) ? NaN : isNaN(a) ? b : isNaN(b) ? a  : a<b ? a : b   # get minimum incl. NaN

# create prominence table
set print $Prominence
    do for [n0=0:|$Peaks|-1]  {
        xn = yn = xp = yp = NaN
        stats $Peaks u ($0<n0 && $2>y0 ? (xn=$1,yn=$2) : 0, \
                        $0>n0 && $2>y0 && yp!=yp ? (xp=$1,yp=$2) : 0, \
                        $0==n0+1 ? (x1=$1, y1=$2) : 0 ) nooutput
        print sprintf("%g %g %g",x0,y0, min(x0-xn,xp-x0))
        x0=x1
        y0=y1
    }
set print

set key noautotitle
set offsets 0,0,1,0
set grid y

# filter Peaks
stats $Prominence u 3 name "P" nooutput      # get min, max
Filter(col,t) = (!valid(col) ? 0 : (1-(column(col)-P_min)/(P_max-P_min))*99+1)<=t ? $2 : NaN

Threshold = 100
set label 1 at graph 0.02,0.95 sprintf("Threshold: %g",Threshold)

plot FILE u colX:colY w l lc rgb "blue" ti "Spectrum", \
     $Prominence u 1:(Filter(3,Threshold)) w impulses lc rgb "red", \
     $Prominence u 1:(Filter(3,Threshold)):1 w labels offset 0,1
### end of script
```

**Results:** (for different thresholds)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]