# Mark roots of a function in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm totally new to Gnuplot and what I want to do is to mark (somehow) all of the roots of my simple function. I know that I can change my line style etc, but how to do this for only these points where y=0? Is it problem solvable with conditional ploting?

I do not use any .dat file wih my points listed inside, just a simple commands like

```
set xzeroaxis
plot x*x*x - x - 2
```

If there is no way to mark these points on a plot, maybe any other way to list them? Write these values somewhere on a plot or something? I'd appreciate every answer.

Comment: Even if you can find an hack, gnuplot is not meant to do solve calculus problems, I would use an external tool like python/numpy : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it ain't pretty. For an explanation of the code see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173128/find-local-maximum-of-data-files-in-gnuplot/28175492#28175492).

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set table "temp"
plot "+" u (x=$1, y=x*x*x - x - 2, x):(y) not
unset table

xcolumn=1
ycolumn=2

plot 0 not, "< grep -v u temp" w l not, "" u (column(0)==0 ? \
(last2y=column(ycolumn), \
last2x=column(xcolumn), 1/0) : column(0)==1 ? (lasty=column(ycolumn), \
lastx=column(xcolumn), 1/0) : last2x+(lastx-last2x)/(lasty-last2y)*(-last2y)): \
( sgn(last2y) != sgn(lasty) ? (value=0., last2y=lasty, last2x=lastx, \
lasty=column(ycolumn), lastx=column(xcolumn), value) : (last2y=lasty, \
last2x=lastx, lasty=column(ycolumn), lastx=column(xcolumn), 1/0) ) pt 7 not
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have to be pretty if it works properly. Could I ask - since it really ain't easy to rewrite these commands, does gnuplot have any option to import these? `gnuplot < plot` where `plot` file contains coded above doesn't work. Please?

Comment: Load function is what I want, nailed it.