# Plotting XRD pattern in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I wish to plot a XRD pattern using Gnuplot. The data file is given below

```
# User : 
# Journal : 
# Sample Details : 
# Col 1: 2theta (deg.), Col 2: Intensity (a.u.)  
20  88
20.05   92
20.1    96
20.15   88
20.2    84
20.25   100
20.3    94
20.35   84
20.4    78
20.45   81
20.5    86
20.55   92
20.6    85
20.65   74
20.7    83
20.75   74
20.8    87
20.85   67
20.9    85
20.95   83
21  90
21.05   81
21.1    87
21.15   84
21.2    83
21.25   84
21.3    86
21.35   92
21.4    92
21.45   73
21.5    97
21.55   96
21.6    88
21.65   95
21.7    93
21.75   83
21.8    91
21.85   91
21.9    76
21.95   85
22  89
22.05   87
22.1    72
22.15   85
22.2    71
22.25   68
22.3    75
22.35   63
22.4    64
22.45   76
22.5    72
22.55   78
22.6    62
22.65   80
22.7    80
22.75   78
22.8    85
22.85   62
22.9    74
22.95   84
23  73
23.05   76
23.1    83
23.15   48
23.2    74
23.25   79
23.3    75
23.35   70
23.4    94
23.45   80
23.5    79
23.55   69
23.6    73
23.65   55
23.7    72
23.75   59
23.8    87
23.85   76
23.9    70
23.95   76
24  74
24.05   76
24.1    89
24.15   79
24.2    84
24.25   72
24.3    69
24.35   74
24.4    72
24.45   85
24.5    65
24.55   85
24.6    68
24.65   71
24.7    70
24.75   70
24.8    75
24.85   73
24.9    79
24.95   76
25  78
25.05   68
25.1    67
25.15   62
25.2    72
25.25   65
25.3    78
25.35   74
25.4    67
25.45   77
25.5    70
25.55   82
25.6    80
25.65   64
25.7    71
25.75   67
25.8    70
25.85   73
25.9    80
25.95   69
26  61
26.05   82
26.1    86
26.15   83
26.2    88
26.25   68
26.3    78
26.35   66
26.4    71
26.45   69
26.5    61
26.55   73
26.6    74
26.65   83
26.7    72
26.75   82
26.8    84
26.85   72
26.9    68
26.95   72
27  63
27.05   66
27.1    68
27.15   65
27.2    75
27.25   72
27.3    66
27.35   58
27.4    67
27.45   73
27.5    74
27.55   84
27.6    80
27.65   82
27.7    70
27.75   71
27.8    70
27.85   76
27.9    73
27.95   85
28  82
28.05   75
28.1    70
28.15   85
28.2    80
28.25   96
28.3    126
28.35   173
28.4    219
28.45   270
28.5    214
28.55   158
28.6    105
28.65   78
28.7    75
28.75   82
28.8    83
28.85   74
28.9    79
28.95   77
29  61
29.05   75
29.1    75
29.15   65
29.2    69
29.25   79
29.3    68
29.35   78
29.4    74
29.45   57
29.5    75
29.55   65
29.6    69
29.65   83
29.7    72
29.75   69
29.8    65
29.85   68
29.9    89
29.95   79
30  84
30.05   110
30.1    129
30.15   146
30.2    150
30.25   136
30.3    117
30.35   81
30.4    72
30.45   85
30.5    75
30.55   71
30.6    70
30.65   72
30.7    87
30.75   67
30.8    71
30.85   75
30.9    80
30.95   76
31  78
31.05   72
31.1    66
31.15   85
31.2    61
31.25   62
31.3    69
31.35   75
31.4    51
31.45   48
31.5    55
31.55   77
31.6    66
31.65   84
31.7    64
31.75   69
31.8    74
31.85   53
31.9    77
31.95   68
32  74
32.05   53
32.1    67
32.15   61
32.2    68
32.25   77
32.3    62
32.35   57
32.4    62
32.45   62
32.5    62
32.55   66
32.6    56
32.65   55
32.7    62
32.75   61
32.8    67
32.85   74
32.9    49
32.95   66
33  82
33.05   57
33.1    59
33.15   61
33.2    62
33.25   74
33.3    60
33.35   72
33.4    66
33.45   71
33.5    58
33.55   66
33.6    59
33.65   66
33.7    53
33.75   70
33.8    52
33.85   66
33.9    58
33.95   65
34  47
34.05   51
34.1    56
34.15   55
34.2    77
34.25   70
34.3    64
34.35   59
34.4    62
34.45   51
34.5    62
34.55   48
34.6    45
34.65   59
34.7    65
34.75   64
34.8    83
34.85   75
34.9    125
34.95   149
35  152
35.05   120
35.1    84
35.15   76
35.2    70
35.25   63
35.3    68
35.35   51
35.4    64
35.45   62
35.5    58
35.55   63
35.6    67
35.65   68
35.7    62
35.75   58
35.8    59
35.85   48
35.9    53
35.95   55
36  54
36.05   56
36.1    49
36.15   53
36.2    66
36.25   60
36.3    63
36.35   61
36.4    48
36.45   67
36.5    61
36.55   50
36.6    48
36.65   46
36.7    70
36.75   54
36.8    62
36.85   62
36.9    45
36.95   56
37  44
37.05   59
37.1    58
37.15   53
37.2    49
37.25   49
37.3    54
37.35   51
37.4    48
37.45   49
37.5    56
37.55   47
37.6    53
37.65   50
37.7    47
37.75   48
37.8    64
37.85   61
37.9    56
37.95   44
38  44
38.05   43
38.1    45
38.15   51
38.2    61
38.25   48
38.3    39
38.35   58
38.4    50
38.45   56
38.5    49
38.55   54
38.6    47
38.65   47
38.7    46
38.75   49
38.8    43
38.85   50
38.9    51
38.95   60
39  69
39.05   46
39.1    68
39.15   44
39.2    42
39.25   46
39.3    52
39.35   43
39.4    46
39.45   52
39.5    57
39.55   46
39.6    48
39.65   47
39.7    51
39.75   61
39.8    48
39.85   53
39.9    59
39.95   46
40  53
40.05   51
40.1    49
40.15   56
40.2    49
40.25   50
40.3    52
40.35   58
40.4    62
40.45   99
40.5    119
40.55   161
40.6    135
40.65   163
40.7    130
40.75   105
40.8    80
40.85   68
40.9    53
40.95   55
41  53
41.05   54
41.1    59
41.15   56
41.2    53
41.25   52
41.3    46
41.35   47
41.4    44
41.45   57
41.5    49
41.55   48
41.6    42
41.65   45
41.7    46
41.75   48
41.8    44
41.85   51
41.9    45
41.95   54
42  44
42.05   46
42.1    43
42.15   53
42.2    50
42.25   38
42.3    42
42.35   51
42.4    51
42.45   42
42.5    36
42.55   36
42.6    53
42.65   44
42.7    38
42.75   45
42.8    55
42.85   33
42.9    50
42.95   58
43  48
43.05   46
43.1    51
43.15   44
43.2    58
43.25   47
43.3    47
43.35   59
43.4    42
43.45   50
43.5    50
43.55   45
43.6    48
43.65   51
43.7    38
43.75   51
43.8    57
43.85   49
43.9    59
43.95   40
44  41
44.05   39
44.1    37
44.15   43
44.2    43
44.25   52
44.3    50
44.35   46
44.4    41
44.45   48
44.5    44
44.55   40
44.6    47
44.65   39
44.7    49
44.75   49
44.8    44
44.85   38
44.9    44
44.95   53
45  46
45.05   51
45.1    31
45.15   38
45.2    51
45.25   42
45.3    47
45.35   46
45.4    37
45.45   66
45.5    53
45.55   40
45.6    45
45.65   39
45.7    47
45.75   39
45.8    45
45.85   38
45.9    48
45.95   42
46  35
46.05   46
46.1    45
46.15   34
46.2    55
46.25   39
46.3    35
46.35   50
46.4    32
46.45   49
46.5    50
46.55   36
46.6    46
46.65   51
46.7    41
46.75   41
46.8    53
46.85   54
46.9    50
46.95   43
47  44
47.05   61
47.1    36
47.15   43
47.2    48
47.25   38
47.3    46
47.35   48
47.4    51
47.45   42
47.5    51
47.55   37
47.6    40
47.65   49
47.7    33
47.75   36
47.8    41
47.85   49
47.9    39
47.95   42
48  58
48.05   51
48.1    43
48.15   48
48.2    46
48.25   34
48.3    44
48.35   39
48.4    44
48.45   46
48.5    35
48.55   35
48.6    51
48.65   43
48.7    45
48.75   54
48.8    48
48.85   41
48.9    49
48.95   52
49  36
49.05   42
49.1    38
49.15   44
49.2    44
49.25   38
49.3    49
49.35   54
49.4    52
49.45   39
49.5    41
49.55   66
49.6    51
49.65   38
49.7    34
49.75   52
49.8    46
49.85   60
49.9    47
49.95   45
50  68
50.05   66
50.1    68
50.15   89
50.2    133
50.25   137
50.3    125
50.35   124
50.4    103
50.45   88
50.5    72
50.55   59
50.6    56
50.65   46
50.7    39
50.75   51
50.8    27
50.85   45
50.9    41
50.95   43
51  51
51.05   49
51.1    45
51.15   38
51.2    48
51.25   43
51.3    42
51.35   44
51.4    45
51.45   49
51.5    40
51.55   43
51.6    37
51.65   50
51.7    47
51.75   37
51.8    39
51.85   43
51.9    42
51.95   40
52  45
52.05   34
52.1    32
52.15   43
52.2    37
52.25   47
52.3    62
52.35   36
52.4    45
52.45   36
52.5    37
52.55   38
52.6    37
52.65   35
52.7    38
52.75   47
52.8    40
52.85   50
52.9    50
52.95   44
53  44
53.05   35
53.1    46
53.15   43
53.2    40
53.25   57
53.3    29
53.35   39
53.4    39
53.45   43
53.5    51
53.55   44
53.6    53
53.65   40
53.7    41
53.75   59
53.8    46
53.85   46
53.9    57
53.95   52
54  48
54.05   50
54.1    40
54.15   42
54.2    46
54.25   48
54.3    47
54.35   42
54.4    49
54.45   43
54.5    43
54.55   54
54.6    44
54.65   40
54.7    45
54.75   34
54.8    42
54.85   40
54.9    34
54.95   43
55  51
55.05   56
55.1    42
55.15   37
55.2    41
55.25   49
55.3    53
55.35   46
55.4    47
55.45   39
55.5    43
55.55   43
55.6    41
55.65   38
55.7    36
55.75   55
55.8    45
55.85   37
55.9    47
55.95   50
56  46
56.05   51
56.1    51
56.15   56
56.2    31
56.25   44
56.3    41
56.35   45
56.4    45
56.45   49
56.5    45
56.55   60
56.6    30
56.65   38
56.7    51
56.75   54
56.8    45
56.85   38
56.9    40
56.95   41
57  36
57.05   35
57.1    45
57.15   41
57.2    49
57.25   36
57.3    38
57.35   43
57.4    43
57.45   41
57.5    42
57.55   42
57.6    41
57.65   39
57.7    37
57.75   48
57.8    42
57.85   56
57.9    45
57.95   39
58  51
58.05   40
58.1    47
58.15   39
58.2    46
58.25   37
58.3    41
58.35   36
58.4    50
58.45   42
58.5    58
58.55   36
58.6    59
58.65   57
58.7    57
58.75   68
58.8    61
58.85   68
58.9    58
58.95   54
59  53
59.05   59
59.1    48
59.15   49
59.2    42
59.25   49
59.3    45
59.35   38
59.4    44
59.45   54
59.5    37
59.55   52
59.6    62
59.65   70
59.7    73
59.75   88
59.8    69
59.85   62
59.9    60
59.95   51
60  59
60.05   51
60.1    45
60.15   45
60.2    39
60.25   55
60.3    48
60.35   45
60.4    34
60.45   47
60.5    32
60.55   40
60.6    40
60.65   54
60.7    35
60.75   50
60.8    40
60.85   34
60.9    39
60.95   31
61  27
61.05   45
61.1    47
61.15   41
61.2    34
61.25   46
61.3    42
61.35   33
61.4    45
61.45   41
61.5    31
61.55   42
61.6    40
61.65   32
61.7    35
61.75   33
61.8    45
61.85   48
61.9    50
61.95   44
62  36
62.05   34
62.1    44
62.15   47
62.2    40
62.25   42
62.3    50
62.35   51
62.4    43
62.45   46
62.5    59
62.55   50
62.6    56
62.65   63
62.7    67
62.75   54
62.8    61
62.85   54
62.9    43
62.95   44
63  36
63.05   49
63.1    41
63.15   46
63.2    44
63.25   36
63.3    34
63.35   36
63.4    58
63.45   42
63.5    40
63.55   48
63.6    43
63.65   35
63.7    36
63.75   42
63.8    41
63.85   40
63.9    39
63.95   40
64  32
64.05   46
64.1    44
64.15   41
64.2    44
64.25   35
64.3    45
64.35   46
64.4    37
64.45   43
64.5    36
64.55   40
64.6    36
64.65   45
64.7    38
64.75   42
64.8    37
64.85   39
64.9    50
64.95   40
65  28
65.05   34
65.1    41
65.15   42
65.2    40
65.25   45
65.3    34
65.35   44
65.4    49
65.45   49
65.5    46
65.55   36
65.6    40
65.65   51
65.7    30
65.75   48
65.8    34
65.85   52
65.9    32
65.95   43
66  41
66.05   42
66.1    61
66.15   57
66.2    55
66.25   44
66.3    63
66.35   78
66.4    80
66.45   77
66.5    98
66.55   86
66.6    81
66.65   61
66.7    62
66.75   59
66.8    54
66.85   50
66.9    52
66.95   32
67  35
67.05   39
67.1    47
67.15   39
67.2    51
67.25   53
67.3    35
67.35   41
67.4    38
67.45   25
67.5    48
67.55   41
67.6    37
67.65   45
67.7    37
67.75   29
67.8    32
67.85   28
67.9    31
67.95   41
68  33
68.05   44
68.1    48
68.15   39
68.2    46
68.25   49
68.3    39
68.35   40
68.4    50
68.45   40
68.5    54
68.55   44
68.6    35
68.65   31
68.7    46
68.75   28
68.8    38
68.85   29
68.9    34
68.95   43
69  49
69.05   37
69.1    43
69.15   44
69.2    31
69.25   33
69.3    43
69.35   47
69.4    42
69.45   39
69.5    37
69.55   35
69.6    42
69.65   44
69.7    37
69.75   53
69.8    24
69.85   35
69.9    41
69.95   34
70  42
70.05   37
70.1    22
70.15   47
70.2    35
70.25   31
70.3    52
70.35   37
70.4    41
70.45   40
70.5    47
70.55   44
70.6    39
70.65   47
70.7    30
70.75   39
70.8    41
70.85   36
70.9    25
70.95   41
71  33
71.05   35
71.1    32
71.15   35
71.2    38
71.25   45
71.3    45
71.35   57
71.4    41
71.45   30
71.5    28
71.55   34
71.6    42
71.65   41
71.7    32
71.75   25
71.8    43
71.85   45
71.9    33
71.95   34
72  44
72.05   43
72.1    45
72.15   42
72.2    42
72.25   30
72.3    44
72.35   47
72.4    36
72.45   45
72.5    40
72.55   45
72.6    33
72.65   39
72.7    47
72.75   39
72.8    40
72.85   34
72.9    39
72.95   30
73  31
73.05   37
73.1    35
73.15   39
73.2    37
73.25   34
73.3    38
73.35   41
73.4    34
73.45   50
73.5    46
73.55   44
73.6    54
73.65   57
73.7    81
73.75   71
73.8    83
73.85   80
73.9    70
73.95   50
74  61
74.05   39
74.1    58
74.15   46
74.2    33
74.25   40
74.3    41
74.35   38
74.4    48
74.45   49
74.5    46
74.55   39
74.6    46
74.65   43
74.7    31
74.75   37
74.8    32
74.85   32
74.9    44
74.95   34
75  29
75.05   31
75.1    33
75.15   52
75.2    32
75.25   29
75.3    29
75.35   36
75.4    28
75.45   28
75.5    45
75.55   25
75.6    30
75.65   26
75.7    32
75.75   32
75.8    44
75.85   40
75.9    30
75.95   34
76  44
76.05   41
76.1    46
76.15   30
76.2    39
76.25   38
76.3    43
76.35   30
76.4    47
76.45   31
76.5    34
76.55   36
76.6    45
76.65   36
76.7    32
76.75   30
76.8    34
76.85   37
76.9    37
76.95   41
77  37
77.05   30
77.1    40
77.15   47
77.2    34
77.25   44
77.3    35
77.35   41
77.4    33
77.45   36
77.5    29
77.55   38
77.6    32
77.65   45
77.7    34
77.75   29
77.8    36
77.85   33
77.9    35
77.95   34
78  40
78.05   43
78.1    33
78.15   35
78.2    40
78.25   43
78.3    38
78.35   38
78.4    43
78.45   40
78.5    42
78.55   38
78.6    34
78.65   34
78.7    40
78.75   37
78.8    37
78.85   39
78.9    47
78.95   40
79  35
79.05   34
79.1    40
79.15   39
79.2    33
79.25   38
79.3    32
79.35   48
79.4    39
79.45   35
79.5    37
79.55   32
79.6    40
79.65   36
79.7    40
79.75   40
79.8    26
79.85   39
79.9    49
79.95   36
80  43
```

My script is provided below

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 4in,3in  
set output "XRD_E1.eps"

set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "black"
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set yrange [0:350]
set format y ''
set tics font ",16"
set xlabel "2{/Symbol \161} (deg.)"  font ",16"
set ylabel "Intensity (a.u.)" font ",16"
set key inside right top  
set key title "As prepared LiCl-KCl \n " font ",14" 
##
set label 1 '(200)' font ",12" at 28.45, 280 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50, 0.50 rotate by 90
set label 2 '(111)' font ",12" at 30.20, 160 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 3 '(200)' font ",12" at 35.00, 160 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 4 '(220)' font ",12" at 40.65, 173 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 5 '(220)' font ",12" at 50.25, 147 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 6 '(400)' font ",12" at 58.85, 78 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -1.00,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 7 '(311)' font ",12" at 59.75, 98 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 8 '(222)' font ",12" at 62.70, 77 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 9 '(420)' font ",12" at 66.50, 108 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 10 '(222)' font ",12" at 73.80, 93 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##

plot [10:90] 'XRD_E1.dat' u 1:2 w l ls 1 notitle
```

The script works fine. I only need to include the point types used in the plot in the key title with a proper spacing.

Secondly, is there a better way to plot and label than what is provided in the script?
Thank you

Comment: What do you want to have in the key? A red and blue dot? But what should be the keyentry? Check `help keyentry` (I guess requires gnuplot >5.2.x). Maybe the following is also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606820/7295599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Suddhasattwa Ghosh, in case this is still of interest, you can simply plot your marks `with labels point` (check `help labels`). Put your peak data into a datablock or in separate files.

**Script:**

```
### print with labels and points
reset session

FILE = 'XRD_E1.dat'
set tics font ",16"
set xlabel "2{/Symbol \161} (deg.)"  font ",16"
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ylabel "Intensity (a.u.)" font ",16"
set yrange [0:350]
set format y ''
set ytics out scale 1.5
set key inside right top noautotitle font ",12" title "As prepared LiCl-KCl \n " font ",14"

$LiCl <<EOD
(200)   28.45   280
(220)   40.65   173
(400)   58.85    78
(420)   66.50   108
EOD

$KCl <<EOD
(111)   30.20   160
(200)   35.00   160
(220)   50.25   147
(311)   59.75    98
(222)   62.70    77
(222)   73.80    93
EOD

plot FILE u 1:2 w l lc "black", \
     $LiCl u 2:3:1 w labels point pt 7 lc "red"  offset -0.5,0.5 left rotate by 90 font ",12" ti "LiCl", \
     $KCl  u 2:3:1 w labels point pt 7 lc "blue" offset -0.5,0.5 left rotate by 90 font ",12" ti "KCl"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want something like this:

[image: horizontal key]

To achieve this, extend your code with:

```
set key horizontal
plot [10:90] 'XRD_E1.dat' u 1:2 w l ls 1 notitle, 1/0 w p pt 7 ps 1.75 lc rgb "red" t 'LiCl', 1/0 w p pt 7 ps 1.75 lc rgb "blue" t 'KCl'
```