# In gnuplot show only the maxmimum point of the graph and highlight it

Tags: gnuplot

In Gnuplot I write below code:

```
set xlabel "Time in Seconds"
set ylabel "Resistance in Ohms"

while(1){
set multiplot layout 2, 1 title " " font ",12"
set tmargin 1.5
 
set title "MQ7 Gas Sensor Data"
unset key
    plot 'putty2.log' using 0:1 with lines ,'' using 0:2:2 with labels center boxed bs 1 notitle column
set title "MQ9 Gas Sensor Data"
unset key
    plot 'putty2.log' using 0:3 with lines
    
pause 1; 
reread;
}
```

This code is described by drawing the multiplot of the data file 'putty.log' in Gnuplot. After doing this I got this:
[image: result]
but I want to show only the maximum point in the 1st multigraph.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show only the global maximum point as label and point or multiple maxima points? In the first case check `help stats`. In the latter case the following might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606820/7295599

Comment: I want multiple Maxima points. Ok I will check it. If any doubt I will get back to you.

Comment: For automated extracting of maxima, probably averaging or smoothing might be helpful because your data has quite some noise and spikes.

Comment: Problem solved? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As starting point, the following script is a simple way to identify maxima in noisy curves. Actually, the random test data generation takes almost more lines than the maxima extraction.

On the smoothened curve you simply check if the 3 consecutive y-values `y0,y1,y2` fulfil `y0<y1 && y1>y2`, then you have a maximum at `y1`.

The smoothing via `smooth bezier` might not be suitable for all type of data. Maybe some averaging together with smoothing might lead to better results.
For example, in the example below the human eye would also detect maxima at 35 and 42.

Futhermore, if you also want to display the y-values of the maxima, the Bezier smoothing probably will mostly return too low values compared to what averaging would give.
I hope you can optimize the script for your data and special needs.

**Script:**

```
### find maxima on smoothened data
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Backbone
    set samples 30
    plot [0:100] '+' u 1:(rand(0)*10+10) w table
set table $CSpline
    set samples 1000
    plot $Backbone u 1:2 smooth cspline
set table $Data
    noise(h)   = (rand(0)*2-1)*h
    spike(p,h) =  rand(0) < p ? (rand(0)*2-1)*h : 0
    plot $CSpline u 1:($2 + noise(1) + spike(0.2,3)) w table
unset table

# smooth the data to facilitate identification of maxima
set table $Smooth
    set samples 200
    plot $Data u 1:2 smooth bezier
unset table

# simple maxima extraction
set table $Maxima
    plot x2=x1=y2=y1=NaN $Smooth u (x0=x1,x1=x2,x2=$1,y0=y1,y1=y2,y2=$2, y0<y1 && y1>y2 ? x1 : NaN):(y1) w table
unset table

set yrange[0:]
set key noautotitle

plot $Data   u 1:2 w l lc "red", \
     $Smooth u 1:2 w l lc "blue", \
     $Maxima u 1:2 w impulses lc "black", \
          '' u 1:(0):(sprintf("%.2f",$1)) w labels left offset 1,0.5 rotate by 90 tc "blue"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]