# plot of spectra UV/VIS in Gnuplot

Tags: python, gnuplot

do you know if there is some function/script to plot data from UV/VIS spectrum in Gnuplot or maybe Python? Basically, I have the following data:

```
Wavelength  Intensity
     360.1  0.00003
     358.2  0.004
     357    0.0001
     355    0.0007
     352.3  0.018
     352    0.000001
     349    0.0001
     348    0.0005
     346    0.0033
```

With Avogadro, I have been able to get a plot but the features are limited. For instance, I cannot change the size of the lines among others. I would like to have the delta peaks and also a curve (collection of Gaussians) that shows the trend of the peaks in the same plot. I found this page: https://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_spectrum.htm where *csplines* is used but in my case, I would like to have a function such as the one used in Avogadro where one specifies the width of the Gaussian and the data are fit accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The question is too broad and misses a clear example (or is about a library recommendation and thus off topic), please make it about a specific programming issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please show your (non-working) script?
As longterm SO-user you should know that some own research effort is expected.
You neither show code nor show (realistic) example data to give an impression what type spectra you are talking about, i.e. how many peaks, how narrow, how noisy, etc.? If you want to fit Gaussian curves to your peaks you have to define a function with appropriate number of Gaussian peaks. Your question is too unspecific to give good advice. Please show some reasonable test data. What is the "function such as the one used in Avogadro"?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71957452/7295599

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Basically, the situation is what I described above, (x,y) points. In Avogadro software, there is some built-in function that smooths out the deltas and create a spectra with fitted Gaussians. I am looking for the algorithm but I am not sure if that is reported anywhere. csplines smooths out the deltas but because the points are not regularly spaced, csplines shows negative values. In the link I posted above, the author wrote some points with y=0 values but this seems to me arbitrary. I will try your suggestion @theozh

Comment: @armando please show some example data and a example graph! If you are interested in peak heights and Gaussian FWHMs then the link I suggested is not the right thing. Therefore, in order to make any useful suggestion we need your data!

Comment: I added some data, the Gnuplot code I am using is: plot 'test.dat'  smooth csplines

Comment: Is this your real spectral data? A bit narrow range and a very low number of datapoints. It will be difficult to fit a useful Gaussian into it. From your description, it sound like you have multiple peaks which you want to fit, right?

Comment: It is not the real spectral data, but I just used some patterns. Yes, there are only a few data points because they were obtained through an ab-initio simulation. Yes, I want to fit Gaussians, if two points are very close the Gaussian should be broader and higher, this is what Avogadro does

Comment: my initial question was more related to knowing if there was any feature (or anybody had a script) in Gnuplot that allows doing the fitting, otherwise, I will write a code to get some fit Gaussians

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot has a smoothing option `kdensity` that fits Gaussian kernels to your data. A portion of the documentation section is copied below. Note that the bandwidth parameter is critical.

```
plot DATA smooth kdensity {bandwidth} {period}

 The `smooth kdensity` option generates and plots a kernel density estimate
 using Gaussian kernels for the distribution from which a set of values was
 drawn.  Values are taken from the first data column, optional weights are
 taken from the second column.  A Gaussian is placed at the location of each
 point and the sum of all these Gaussians is plotted as a function.
 To obtain a normalized histogram, each weight should be 1/number-of-points.

 Bandwidth:
 By default gnuplot calculates and uses the bandwidth which would be optimal
 for normally distributed data values.
      default_bandwidth = sigma * (4/3N) ** (0.2)
 This will usually be a very conservative, i.e. broad bandwidth.
 Alternatively, you can provide an explicit bandwidth.
 The bandwidth used in the previous plot is stored in GPVAL_KDENSITY_BANDWIDTH.
```

Here is a plot using your sample data and a fixed bandwidth:

```
plot $DATA smooth kdensity bandwidth 1 with lines title "smooth kdensity", \
     $DATA with impulses title "impulse"
```

[image]